# Need help Sending User Id from client to server using assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, system-calls, uid

I am fairly new to assembly and am trying to create a client which will connect to a server and communicate the user's id. I use the getuid system call. 
I have tried printing it directly in client as well, but that doesnt work either.

```
global _start

struc sockaddr_in
    .sin_family resw 1
    .sin_port resw 1
    .sin_addr resd 1
    .sin_zero resb 8
endstruc

; Convert numbers (constants!) to network byte order
%define hton(x) ((x & 0xFF000000) >> 24) | ((x & 0x00FF0000) >>  8) | ((x & 0x0000FF00) <<  8) | ((x & 0x000000FF) << 24)
%define htons(x) ((x >> 8) & 0xFF) | ((x & 0xFF) << 8)

AF_INET        equ 2
SOCK_STREAM    equ 1
INADDR_ANY  equ 0   ; /usr/include/linux/in.h

STDIN          equ 0
STDOUT         equ 1

__NR_exit   equ 1
__NR_read       equ 3
__NR_write      equ 4
__NR_close  equ 6
__NR_socketcall equ 102
__NR_getuid equ 24

; commands for sys_socketcall
; /usr/include/linux/in.h
SYS_SOCKET  equ 1
SYS_BIND    equ 2
SYS_CONNECT equ 3
SYS_LISTEN  equ 4
SYS_ACCEPT  equ 5
SYS_SEND    equ 9
SYS_RECV    equ 10
;------------------------


_ip equ 0x7F000001      ; loopback - 127.0.0.1
_port equ 31337

; Convert 'em to network byte order
IP equ hton(_ip)
PORT equ htons(_port)

BUFLEN         equ  1000

section .data

my_sa istruc sockaddr_in
    at sockaddr_in.sin_family, dw AF_INET
    at sockaddr_in.sin_port, dw PORT
    at sockaddr_in.sin_addr, dd INADDR_ANY
    at sockaddr_in.sin_zero, dd 0, 0
iend

socket_args dd AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0
connect_args dd 0, my_sa, sockaddr_in_size

section .bss
    my_buf resb BUFLEN
    fd_socket resd 1
    fd_conn resd 1
    id resd 1

section .text
 _start: 

    ; socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    mov ecx, socket_args    ; address of args structure
    mov ebx, SYS_SOCKET     ; subfunction or "command"
    mov eax, __NR_socketcall     ;c.f. /usr/src/linux/net/socket.c
    int 80h

    cmp eax, -4096
    ja exit

    mov [fd_socket], eax
    ; and fill in connect_args, etc.
    mov [connect_args], eax    

    mov ecx, connect_args
    mov ebx, SYS_CONNECT    ; subfunction or "command"
    mov eax, __NR_socketcall
    int 80h

    cmp eax, -4096
    ja exit

    mov [fd_conn], eax    

    xor eax, eax

    ; call getuid()
    mov eax, __NR_getuid
    int 80h

    cmp eax, -4096
    ja exit    

    ;mov eax, '3'
    mov [id], eax

    ; write(sock, buf, len)
    mov edx, 4          ; arg 3: max count
    mov ecx, id         ; arg 2: buffer
    mov ebx, [fd_socket]    ; arg 1: fd
    mov eax, __NR_write     ; sys_write
    int 80h

    cmp eax, -4096
    ja exit


goodexit:
    xor eax, eax        ; success
 exit:
    mov ebx, eax        ; exitcode
    neg ebx
    mov eax, __NR_exit
    int 80h
;-----------------------
```

Basically i dont receive anything on server side with this. But if I send value 3 directly by uncommenting the mov eax line then I can see that 3 coming to server. 
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong ?
I can post the server code as well if wanted. (It's just a basic server in c which prints out everything received from client).

Comment: You have to convert the UID to a string and store it in `id`. It looks like you are sending a raw integer across. When you move `'3'` to `id` you are sending the ASCII code for the letter `3` so it works. If you want the `uid` to be converted to text you will have to do that yourself before sending it. Possibly your server is getting data but you aren't dealing with non printable characters. You could send the raw binary value of `id` but you'll have to convert it to a string on the server side before displaying it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch So basically i have to replicate a sort of sprintf behavior in assembly. Can you give a few hints or point me where I can learn to do that ? Thanks for the reply